# function randomString(): string

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use JavaScript code in an Angular application. I tried this:

```
export class MerchantNewComponent extends FormBaseComponent {

  constructor(private merchantService: MerchantService,
              private router: Router) {
    super();
  }

  function randomString() {
    var length = 40;
    var chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    var result = '';
    for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
    return result;
  }
}
```

But I get this error:

[image]

Does anybody know how I can use this JavaScript code in an Angular application?

Comment: Please post your errors as text.

Comment: One option is to declare the function outside of the class and use it in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the TypeScript syntax to declare a method in a class:

```ts
export class MerchantNewComponent extends FormBaseComponent {

  getRandomStr(): string {
    // ...
  }
}
```

## Notes

1. It's recommended to add the return type of the function next to the function declaration.
2. Consider renaming the function to be more descriptive and to denote that it returns a value. (like what I've done above `randomString` becomes `getRandomStr` - this clarifies what exactly the function does)

For more info, check out the [TypeScript handbook on classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#classes)

---

EDIT: To specify an argument that should be passed into a method, see below:

```ts
getRandomStr(randomLength: number): string {
  // Do something w/ the randomLength variable
  console.log(randomLength);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: What about the vars into the method?

Comment: You can specify an argument in between the brackets.

Answer (score 1):

should be `public randomString` instead of `function randomString`

`function` can be used outside the class, if it is inside, then it is a method of the class, not a function anymore.

If you use it inside the component, you can call it by using `this.randomString()` or `randomString()` in the template

You can also use getter `public get randomString() {...}` then when you use it, you only need to call it as `this.randomString`

Comment: Anything else to change?